# Java for loop by value or by reference

Tags: java, for-loop, reference

I figured out a a problem in my Code. First the code:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] blablubb = { "a", "b", "c" };

        for(String s : blablubb) {
            s = "over";
        }
        printArray(blablubb);


        for (int i = 0; i < blablubb.length; i++) {
            blablubb[i] = "over";
        }
        printArray(blablubb);

    }

    public static void printArray(String[] arr) {
        for( String s : arr ) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
a
b
c
over
over
over
```

I assumed the first loop would also overwrite the String in the array. So the output would be over in any case. It seems it creates a copy of the value instead creating a reference.
I never perceived this. Am I doing it wrong? Is there an option to create a reference instead?

//Edit:
Seems like everybody knows about that except me. I'm from C background and doesn't pay enough attention to the term reference which is very different to C. 
Fortunately it took me just 10 minutes to figure this out (this time).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This:

```
for (String s : blablubb) {
     s = "over";
}
```

Is equal to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blablubb.length; i++) {
     String s = blablubb[i];
     s = "over";
}
```

This creates a temporary String with a copy of the value from array and you change only the copy. That's why `blablubb[]` content stays untouched.

If you want to change values in the array, just use your second option:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blablubb.length; i++) {         
    blablubb[i] = "over";
}
```

And, by the way, you can print an array with just one line:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blablubb));
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `for(String s : blablubb)` loop is equivalent to the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < blablubb.length; i++ ) {
    String s = blablubb[i];
    s = "over";
}
```

Hopefully, from this you can see that all you are doing is reassigning a different value to `s` without changing `blablubb[i]`. This explains the output you see.

Answer (score 2):

The for-each loop don't modify the objects contained in the Collection of objects it's iterating over. It's passing the value not the reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
 s = "over";
```

just changes the reference of s and not the String in the array.

```
blablubb[i] = "over";
```

changes the value stored at ith location in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String s : StringArray)
{
}
```

is like

```
for(int i = 0; i < StringArray.length; i++)
{
    String s = StringArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to do a low level optimization, know how, you have to look inside Java code and inside byte-code either(compiled code)

```
for(String s : blablubb) {
            s = "over";
}
```

is equals with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blablubb.length; i++) {
     String s = blablubb[i];            
     s = "over";
}
```

and that's why the output as how it is.